# What brick number is this?

Tags: part-identification

Can anyone help us to identify what this part number is?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Bricks.SE!

Answer (score 10):

That's [18649](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=18649#T=C) - Plate, Modified 1 x 2 with Handles on Ends